# why change the left of an element with matrix3d won't trigger repaint

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, css-transforms

It is a bit difficult to describe, so I split it into several steps:

1. I open the `Show paint rectangles` option on chrome **DevTool**.
2. I open a web page find an element, and change the left or top property of the element.
3. I can see the element move and a green rectangle appears on the element.
4. I find another element with a CSS property "transform" and value.

> matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);

5. I change this element's left and top.
6. I can still see the element move, but there is not a green rectangle appear on this element.Maybe that means the moving of the element did't trigger repainting of the page.

What's more, when I change the "opacity" of the element, the same thing happens too.

So why is the `matrix3d` prevent the repaint ?

I have watched this video:[Why Moving Elements With Translate() Is Better Than Pos:abs Top/left](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/), it seems that changing of "left" and "top" are not handled by GPU.So I'm confused.

Comment: They are handled by the GPU, take a look at http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/03/18/css-animations-and-transitions-performance/  or look at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/